# Is there a proper way to add a Subtitle in a NavigationStack?

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios16

I'm using the `.toolbar` modifier right now in order to put a subtitle under the `navigationTitle` but I've encountered some small - but annoying - UI problems with the simulator, especially when I override some of the stock components of the toolbar.

Back in iOS 15 we had the `NavigationView` which had the `.navigationSubtitle` modifier and it isn't compatible with `NavigationStack`. I can't find anything like that for iOS 16. All I've found is people using the `.toolbar` modifier, but I want to know if there is something stock from Apple like the `navigationSubtitle` in iOS15.